# C# and MySql Inserting Data Error

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a problem in my application that I am developing.

I Insert 4 Data FieldsLets call them (`"Age"`, `"Gender"` , `"Name"`, `"Tel"`) in to a MySQL database. 99% of the time it will work 100% then once in a while I will get something odd.

Row 1 will have the Age , Gender, "Null" , "Null" and row 2 Will have "Null" , "Null" , Name , Tel so basically it will insert one line of data into 2 rows.

Below is the sample of the code:

```
String constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["server"].ConnectionString;
            string Query = "insert into db.Table (Name , Surname , ID , Tel) 
values('" + this.textBox1.Text + "' , '" + this.textBox2.Text + "'  , 
'" + this.textBox6.Text + "'  , '" + this.textBox4.Text + "');";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            conDataBase.Open();
            try
            {


                myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {

                }
                conDataBase.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Cleint Details has been added to system");
        }
```

If anyone can think of a reason for this please help. I did check the environment (network connection etc.) but those are fine.

Comment: When you have this problem, does your data include quotes or anything that could be breaking your SQL statement "incorrectly"?

Comment: From what you stated, there are two queries getting submitted. Your code only shows how a single query gets submitted. I suggest you look at what's triggering your method. I'd also check to see if your code has events that are thrown such that multiple calls of incomplete data might get sent twice under specific circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible there are values in the text box that are affecting the insert statement. It would be better if you used parameterised statements. E.g.:

```
string Query = "insert into db.Table (Name , Surname , ID , Tel) values(@param1, @param2 , @param3  , @param4);";

MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);

//Add paramter values
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", this.textBox1.Text);
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", this.textBox2.Text);
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", this.textBox6.Text);
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param4", this.textBox4.Text);
```

Comment: Hi thank for the feed back this solved it but also not only that it showed me what the user did to make the error happen , if a person has a name like "Mike De'Le" the sql command will stop at the ' and just explode and go wrong. so this solved the problem thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I think Reece's answer is going to solve your problem, but I also recommend ditching the `ExecuteReader()` and `while{}` loop.  Instead just use `cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery();` to fire the insert.